# Switch ServiceBusClient to use HTTP instead of AMQP

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am looking at Azure Service Bus, and am noticing that there is a cost incurred each time I stop and start debugging my Message Bus application.  This is because Brokered Connections incur a $30 cost per 1,000 (after the first 1,000)

From what I can tell, a brokered connection is counted when you connect to the service bus via AMQP or when you use HTTP to listen for messages with a longer than 0 seconds timeout.

For production and testing, I am happy to use AMQP and pay for the connections.  But for development, I would like to not have to pay for a brokered connection for each time a developer stops and starts debugging.

I had hoped that there would be an easy way to swap the Microsoft class ServiceBusClient to use HTTP instead of AMQP, but I am not seeing one.

I thought I would ask if there is a lesser known way to do this?  (Or does everyone just pay the extra for development?)

Comment: ASB .NET SDK support TCP and WebSockets. But both implement AMQP protocol. I'm not sure how you've derived the $30 dollar figure. With a standard tier, development is pretty much at pennies level with $10 per service for all of your namespaces in the Standard tier.

Comment: @SeanFeldman - If you go to the Azure Pricing Calculator and add a Service Bus to the calculator, it has a section for Brokered Connections.  If you enter 1000, the price does not change.  For each additional 1000 you add, the price goes up by $30.  Each connection by an AMQP client counts as a brokered connection.  (Which includes a developer testing, stopping the app and making a change, then running it again.  Something that happens over and over in development.)

Comment: 1000 brokered connections is a 1000 concurrent connections to the namespace. Each connection represents a connection to an entity such as a queue. ASB is stateful, you don't connect and disconnect, but rather use the established connection. IIRC, having _over_ a thousand concurrent connections would have the charge. Are you going to have more than a thousand concurrent connections in you dev environment?

Answer (score 1):

The modern Azure SDK packages for Service Bus support only AMQP.

The Service Bus service itself offers a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/servicebus/service-bus-runtime-rest), but it supports only a subset of service features and is intended, mainly, to support limited operations in constrained environments - such as publishing messages from an IoT device.

While I would strongly recommend against using it, the legacy [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) package still supports the old proprietary SBMP protocol which is - I believe - based on WCF via HTTP.  Though the package is not yet formally deprecated, it is well on its way to being so and is receiving only important security and bug fixes.  It also only supports the desktop .NET framework.

All of that said, I don't have insight on the specifics of how billing is calculated against connections specifically.  I'd recommend that you [open an Azure support request](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to discuss that with an authoritative source.